# Iterate through directories recursively and handle relative paths

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text files with paths to different texts files with paths and so on. Like this:

```
C:\folder1\dirs1.txt:
           folder2\dirs1.txt
           folder2\dirs2.txt
           folder3\dirs1.txt

C:\folder1\folder2\dirs1.txt:
           folder4\dirs1.txt
           folder4\dirs2.txt
```

I need to iterate through all files and print it, it's easy:

```
IEnumerable<string> ExtractAllPathsFromFile(string path) { ... } 

void PrintAllPaths(string root)
{
      var paths = ExtractAllPathsFromFile(root);

      foreach (path in paths)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(path);
         if (File.Exists(path))
            PrintAllPaths(path);
      }
}



PrintAllPaths(root:C:\folder1\dirs1.txt);
```

But as you can see in the example all paths are relative (not absolute), and I need to come up with the idea how to handle it in my algorithm.

Comment: You likely need to specify the initial directory for the _relative_ paths to relate to. After that use your solution like `PrintAllPaths(Path.Combine(initialDirectory, path));` assuming `initialDirectory` is your root and `path` is your relative path.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Path.Combine()` methods to safely concatenate multiple paths. You can get the directory path from `C:\folder1\dirs1.txt` with the `Path.GetDirectoryName()` method. Wouldn't something like this work?

```
using System.IO;

public static string[] ExtractPathsFromFile(string originalPath)
{
    string[] newPaths = File.ReadAllLines(originalPath);
    string[] modified = new string[newPaths.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < newPaths.Length; i++)
        modified[i] = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(originalPath), newPaths[i].Trim());
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, if the examples in the question are right. In the second example the entries read are not relative to the directory of the file from where the entries are read, but to the parent directory (`C:\folder1\folder4\dirs1.txt` instead of `C:\folder1\folder2\folder4\dirs1.txt`).

Comment: From my point of view, if the file `C:\folder1\dirs1.txt` contains the string  `folder2\dirs1.txt`, the path `C:\folder1\folder2\dirs1.txt` should be derived from it. OP states in his question that this file exists, so an explicit concetantion of paths has happend here. And so, at this path, you will find a new textfile, which e.g. contains `folder4\dirs1.txt`, and so the a new path `C:\folder1\folder2\folder4\dirs1.txt` should be derived from it (but sadly OP doesn't state that this is the correct filename). If that's wrong, OP is free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, something like that?

```
  String path = null;

  var files = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFiles.txt")
    .Select(line => {
      if (Path.IsPathRooted(line)) {
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(line);

        return line;
      }
      else
        return  Path.Combine(path, line.Trim());
    });
...

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, files));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean this:

```
IEnumerable<string> ExtractAllPathsFromFile(string path) 
{  
  var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName( path );
  return File.ReadAllLines(path).Select (f => Path.Combine(basePath, f.Trim()));
}
```